# How to Disable UNICODE slug?

Tags: slug, characters

I am inserting the post titles in UNICODE, but i dont want to save in unicode UTF8 characters. Instead, i want to use my title convert function before slug auto-creation:
like this:

```
function my_convert($string)
{
$string = str_replace('ჲ','a',$string);
$string = str_replace('ძ','b',$string);
..............
.............
return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using 3 combined hooks  `wp_insert_post_data`, `wp_ajax_sample-permalink`,`name_save_pre`

```
  //==================DISABLE GEORGIAN + Russian SLUGS for POSTS================
    //disable slug on any update
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'myappend_slug', 3); function myappend_slug($data) {  
        $data['post_name']= slug_modify($data['post_name']);return $data; 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_sample-permalink', 'MyajaxSamplePermalink',1);         function MyajaxSamplePermalink($data) {
        // check that we're dealing with a product, and editing the slug
        $post_id = isset($_POST['post_id']) ? intval($_POST['post_id']) : 0;
        $post_name = isset($_POST['new_slug'])? $_POST['new_slug'] : null;
        $new_title = isset($_POST['new_title'])? $_POST['new_title'] : null;
        $chosen = (isset($post_name) ? $post_name : $new_title );
        $_POST['new_slug'] = slug_modify($chosen);
    }
    add_filter('name_save_pre', 'MyfilterNameSavePre');     function MyfilterNameSavePre($post_name) {
        // check that we're dealing with a product, and editing the slug
        $post_id = isset($_POST['post_ID']) ? intval($_POST['post_ID']) : 0;
        $new_slug = isset($_POST['post_name']) ? $_POST['post_name'] : 0;
        if ($post_id) { $post_name = slug_modify($new_slug); }
        return $post_name;
    }

            function slug_modify($slg) {return myFILTERRRRRRR($slg);}
```

Comment: Please also accept this answer to prevent the question haunting the site every now and then.